# border&grid layouts

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

[image: Sample GUI]Hi everyone I have a problem. If anyone can help it would be great. I am using border and gridlayout and I am trying to split the GUI but it is not happening as  I want the buttons to be a small part of the whole lets say 1/5 but at the moment is more than the half of the GUI.
I also trying putting  the buttons is dimension but I am not sure if it is a good practice.I have two classes one is RunFurniture where is the main method with the frame and the other method is PanelFurniture with the GUI.I am using eclipse and the program is compiling and  running. I hope I gave a good explanation. Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelFurniture extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    JButton center, east;
    JButton[] commandButtons = {
                                 new JButton(" Add Chair"),
                                 new JButton(" Add Table"),
                                 new JButton(" Add Desk "),
                                 new JButton(" Clear All   "),
                                 new JButton("Total Price"),
                                 new JButton("   Save       "),
                                 new JButton("   Load       "),
                                 new JButton("Summary ")
                                                        };

    JPanel centerPanel, westPanel, eastPanel;

    PanelFurniture()
    {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        for(int i=0; i<commandButtons.length; i++)      
        {
            westPanel.add(commandButtons[i]);
            commandButtons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
//      westPanel.setSize(westDimension);   
        this.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // start the middle panel       
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

        center = new JButton("center");
        centerPanel.add(center);
        east = new JButton("east");
        centerPanel.add(east);  


        this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {




    }
}
```

### RunRurniture

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RunRurniture 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        PanelFurniture panel = new PanelFurniture();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(300,150);
        application.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        application.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Those buttons in WEST might be better suited to being put in a `JToolBar` in the `NORTH`.  OTOH I am not entirely clear how you would like this GUI to appear, or how it should re-assign space when resized. Can you add some ASCII art or drawings of each to explain better?

Comment: ..Also, I'm guessing that `RunRurniture` should be `RunFurniture`.  ;)

Comment: you are quite right about the name of the class

Comment: there is a simple design of what I am  trying to do

Comment: I think, the `JPanel` on the `LINE_START` or `WEST` must have to be with `BoxLayout` with `PAGE_AXIS`, and the `CENTER` JPanel can go with `GridLayout` to accomodate these images :-)

Comment: well what i am trying to do is to put the buttons in borderlayout.west and the rest is going in the borderlayout.center. the center then i split on two with grid and then the grid for both.

Comment: i was thinking to do it with dimensions but i am not sure if it is a good practice

Comment: *"i was thinking to do it with dimensions but i am not sure if it is a good practice"*  Let me clarify for you.  It's not.  Many threads that involve layouts go into it, but don't take the advice of people who are inexperienced in the matter, since it is a common misconception that setting sizes is a normal & optimal thing to do.  It seems I guessed your layout wrong (& Gagandeep pegged it), but please consider my alternate layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few additional suggestions:

- Don't use spaces to do layout; use alignment.
- Let the layout do the work by using the components preferred size.
- Use the [`for-each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) construct where possible.
- Start in the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image: Furniture Test]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9793194/230513 */
public class FurnitureTest {

    private static final class FurniturePanel
        extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private static final int N = 3;
        private static final Icon icon =
            UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        private JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        private JButton[] commandButtons = {
            new JButton("Add Chair"),
            new JButton("Add Table"),
            new JButton("Add Desk"),
            new JButton("Clear All"),
            new JButton("Total Price"),
            new JButton("Save"),
            new JButton("Load"),
            new JButton("Summary")
        };

        FurniturePanel() {
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            westPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(westPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            for (JButton b : commandButtons) {
                b.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                westPanel.add(b);
                b.addActionListener(this);
            }
            this.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

            centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(N, N, N, N));
            for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
                centerPanel.add(new JLabel(icon));
            }
            this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame application = new JFrame();
                FurniturePanel panel = new FurniturePanel();
                application.add(panel);
                application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                application.pack();
                application.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                application.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice example.  And as always, beautiful screen-shot. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Latest Edit :**

I think, the `JPanel` on the `LINE_START` or `WEST` must have to be with `GridLayout`, and the `CENTER` JPanel can go with `GridLayout` to accomodate these images :-) . I was working on it when you accepted this answer and when @AndrewThompson, added that comment regarding `GridLayout` thingy, but seems like putting that JPanel on GridLayout will allow equal size JButtons. Here is my interpretation with `GridLayout` in code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RunFurniture 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        PanelFurniture panel = new PanelFurniture();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.pack();
        application.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        application.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class PanelFurniture extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    JButton center, east;
    JButton[] commandButtons = {
                                 new JButton(" Add Chair"),
                                 new JButton(" Add Table"),
                                 new JButton(" Add Desk "),
                                 new JButton(" Clear All   "),
                                 new JButton("Total Price"),
                                 new JButton("   Save       "),
                                 new JButton("   Load       "),
                                 new JButton("Summary ")
                                                        };

    JPanel centerPanel, westPanel, eastPanel;

    PanelFurniture()
    {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        //westPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(westPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        westPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        for(int i=0; i<commandButtons.length; i++)      
        {
            westPanel.add(commandButtons[i]);
            commandButtons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
//      westPanel.setSize(westDimension);   
        this.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        // start the middle panel       
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

        center = new JButton("center");
        centerPanel.add(center);
        east = new JButton("east");
        centerPanel.add(east);  


        this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {




    }
}
```

Output :

[image: FURNITUREGRIDLAYOUT]

Here is my interpretation with `BoxLayout` in code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RunFurniture 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        PanelFurniture panel = new PanelFurniture();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.pack();
        application.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        application.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class PanelFurniture extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    JButton center, east;
    JButton[] commandButtons = {
                                 new JButton(" Add Chair"),
                                 new JButton(" Add Table"),
                                 new JButton(" Add Desk "),
                                 new JButton(" Clear All   "),
                                 new JButton("Total Price"),
                                 new JButton("   Save       "),
                                 new JButton("   Load       "),
                                 new JButton("Summary ")
                                                        };

    JPanel centerPanel, westPanel, eastPanel;

    PanelFurniture()
    {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        //westPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(westPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        westPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        for(int i=0; i<commandButtons.length; i++)      
        {
            westPanel.add(commandButtons[i]);
            commandButtons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
//      westPanel.setSize(westDimension);   
        this.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        // start the middle panel       
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

        center = new JButton("center");
        centerPanel.add(center);
        east = new JButton("east");
        centerPanel.add(east);  


        this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {




    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: FURNITURE]

Comment: Ah yes, that was another layout I was playing with.  +1  See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: thanks for your time your solutions is suitable for me cheers

Comment: @Kiril : Your are most Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: My first comment was misguided, I thought you were suggesting a single column `GridLayout` which would keep all buttons the same width!  The GL also makes it easy to add extra space between the buttons (though the same can be done in a `BoxLayout` using `JSeparator` instances, I guess).

Comment: +1 example; a minor note on _alignment_, addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9793993/230513).

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Exactly that's what I was working on, to make those `JButton`s of equal size. That's when I thought of `GridLayout`, was making the changes and here I am :-)

Comment: @trashgod : My bad, I never saw that part, was too much in thinking about the layout, so I just noticed only that `frame.setSize(...)` that I changed to `pack()`. This thing you pointed out, I never thought that someone will take that road to make buttons equal :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of what I mentioned in the comment (with a few other tweaks).

[image: PanelFurniture image]

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelFurniture extends JPanel
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4231608548183463223L;

    JButton center, east;
    // leading/trailing spaces in these labels will be ignored.
    JButton[] commandButtons = {
            new JButton("Add Chair"),
            new JButton("Add Table"),
            new JButton("Add Desk "),
            new JButton("Clear All   "),
            new JButton("Total Price"),
            new JButton("Summary "),
            new JButton("Save"),
            new JButton("Load")
    };

    JPanel centerPanel, eastPanel;

    PanelFurniture()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar(); 

        for(int i=0; i<commandButtons.length; i++)      
        {
            if (i==3 || i==6) {
                toolBar.addSeparator();
            }
            toolBar.add(commandButtons[i]);
        }
        this.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // start the middle panel       
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

        center = new JButton("center");
        centerPanel.add(center);
        east = new JButton("east");
        centerPanel.add(east);  

        this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame application = new JFrame();
                PanelFurniture panel = new PanelFurniture();
                application.add(panel);
                application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                application.pack();
                application.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                application.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### Update

This GUI is based on the image.

[image: PanelFurniture 2]

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PanelFurniture extends JPanel
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4231608548183463223L;

    JButton center, east;
    // leading/trailing spaces in these labels will be ignored.
    JButton[] commandButtons = {
            new JButton("Add Chair"),
            new JButton("Add Table"),
            new JButton("Add Desk "),
            new JButton("Clear All   "),
            new JButton("Total Price"),
            new JButton("Summary "),
            new JButton("Save"),
            new JButton("Load")
    };

    JPanel centerPanel, westPanel, westPanelConstrain, eastPanel;

    PanelFurniture()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout(2,2));
        this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        westPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,4,4));

        for(int i=0; i<commandButtons.length; i++)      
        {
            westPanel.add(commandButtons[i]);
        }
        westPanelConstrain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        westPanelConstrain.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(westPanelConstrain, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // start the middle panel       
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

        center = new JButton("center");
        centerPanel.add(center);
        east = new JButton("east");
        centerPanel.add(east);

        this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame application = new JFrame();
                PanelFurniture panel = new PanelFurniture();
                application.add(panel);
                application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                application.pack();
                application.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                application.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it is good but i need the buttons to be from the top to the button

Comment: Now seeing that image, I would go with either Gagandeep or my design for the main buttons, and for the `CENTER`, either a `FlowLayout` or a `JList` with a call to [`setLayoutOrientation(HORIZONTAL_WRAP)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setLayoutOrientation%28int%29).

Comment: See also the update that explains what I mean about using `GridLayout`

Comment: @trashgod  Thanks.  I was waiting for *someone* to say that.  ;)  I relented & provided a 2nd example more to the OP's spec.  'The customer is always right.'