# Creating new object of a class on button click / actionEvent

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

Found solution

decided it was easier to simply make a method outside of the actionListener called chairPrice which can be incremented by a method called getItemPrice(). This has been used to calculate the total price of items and works 100%

Comment: `new Chair()`... you are welcome. Next time try to post a more specific question

Comment: @S92 What exactly is giving you problems about creating a new Chair? Is it actually creating the object, adding it to a list, or what?

Comment: @SJuan76 - i already know about using new Chair() thats not what I wanted I have updated my initial q

Comment: @Andres F. - I want to create multiple instances of the Chair glass to calculate prices of the chairs and work out overall price when using the GUI - I have included a pic of what the GUI looks like hopefully this will help illustrate my problem

Comment: Alternative layouts suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9793194/230513). Is this [tag:homework]?

Comment: The actual GUI layout I have works fine, its just working out the total price of multiple chair items im having trouble with. I thought maybe I had to create multiple instances of the chair class to calculate a totalPrice but im not sure..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Object.equals()` method.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonClick)
{
   if(buttonClick.getSource().equals(guiButtons[0])) //if user clicks on 'add chair'
   {
     Chair chair = new Chair();
   }
}
```

***Edit in response to the OP's comment***

I'm not exactly sure what you're wanting. `myChair` isn't the name of your chair.  It's the name of the variable.  It has no effect on `Chair` at all.  If you want to make a new `Chair` object and have it available for the whole class, you're going to need to either add a new field variable or make a list of `Chair`.

```
public class GuiClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
  List<Chair> chairs = new ArrayList<Chair>(Arrays.asList(new Chair()));
  Desk myDesk = new Desk();
  Table myTable = new Table();

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonClick)
  {
     if(buttonClick.getSource().equals(guiButtons[0])) //if user clicks on 'add chair'
     {
       chairs.add(new Chair());
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: If u look at the code I provided above im already using the following code in GuiClass: Chair myChair = new Chair(); //Object of chair

But I want it to create a new object with a new name everytime buttonClick is guiButtons[0]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help up to now, im having a few problems trying to implement your solution can you please check my revised initial post thanks.

Comment: I think a better way to phrase what I want to know is how to be able to call a method from an object stored inside an ArrayList

because what im currently doing is causing errors which say it can't find the methods such as setIdNum(0)