# Add object for every user input

Tags: java, object, jpanel, jbutton, user-input

I am trying to create a new button every time the user presses a button.

So, if I click "add" button, then a new panel/button/thing would be added to the JPanel.

Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373747/creating-new-object-of-a-class-on-button-click-actionevent) is the same thing I'm asking for

Don't know what

```
guiButtons[0]
```

is in

```
if(buttonClick.getSource().equals(guiButtons[0]))
```

Would be nice if someone could explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as bellow code, may it help you

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton newButton = new JButton("New Added Bnt");
            panel.add(newButton);
        }
    });
```