# Components added outside constructor wont appear

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have one tab that needs to update using one of two methods in it's class while the program is running, for that reason I'm adding components inside the methods, and I cannot get any of them to display. As far as I can tell it's because they are outside the constructor, I used to declare them all inside the methods but moved it to try and fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I apologise it's a bit messy, I've been trying to fix the problem, a bit blindly.

Also the code compiles fine, and println outputs in code display as expected.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assgui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Hugh
 */
public class ResultPanel extends JPanel {

    static String[][] activityString = new String[31][2];
    static String[][] foodString = new String[36][2];

        String weighstr, foodstr, servstr, kjstr, actstr, hourstr, minstr, metstr;

        JLabel uw = new JLabel ("User Weight:  ");
        JLabel weigh = new JLabel (weighstr);
        JLabel kg = new JLabel("  kg");
        JLabel sel1 = new JLabel("Food:  ");
        JLabel sel2 = new JLabel(foodstr);
        JLabel sel3 = new JLabel("  -  kj  ");
        JLabel sel4 = new JLabel(kjstr);
        JLabel sel5 = new JLabel("  ,  Servings:  ");
        JLabel sel6 = new JLabel(servstr);
        JLabel sel7 = new JLabel("Activity for comparison:  ");
        JLabel sel8 = new JLabel(actstr);
        JLabel sel9 = new JLabel("  Time required to balance:  ");
        JLabel sel10 = new JLabel(hourstr);
        JLabel sel11 = new JLabel("  hours");
        JLabel sel12 = new JLabel(minstr);
        JLabel sel13 = new JLabel("  minutes");
        JLabel smlspace = new JLabel("          ");
        JLabel medspace = new JLabel("               ");
        JLabel lrgspace = new JLabel("                         ");

        JLabel auw = new JLabel("User Weight:  ");
        JLabel aweigh = new JLabel(weighstr);
        JLabel akg = new JLabel("  kg");
        JLabel asel1 = new JLabel("Activity:  ");
        JLabel asel2 = new JLabel(actstr);
        JLabel asel3 = new JLabel("  -  MET  ");
        JLabel asel4 = new JLabel(metstr);
        JLabel asel5 = new JLabel("  ,  Duration:  ");
        JLabel asel6 = new JLabel(hourstr);
        JLabel asel7 = new JLabel("  hour  ");
        JLabel asel8 = new JLabel(minstr);
        JLabel asel9 = new JLabel("  minutes  ");
        JLabel asel10 = new JLabel("Food for comparison:  ");
        JLabel asel11 = new JLabel(foodstr);
        JLabel asel12 = new JLabel("  Servings to balance:  ");
        JLabel asel13 = new JLabel(servstr);
        JLabel asmlspace = new JLabel("          ");
        JLabel amedspace = new JLabel("               ");
        JLabel alrgspace = new JLabel("                         ");

        Public ResultPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 600));
        {

    public void activityPaint (String[][] actstring, String[][] foodstring, double        weight, int activity, int hour, int min, int food, double servings) {

        System.out.println("act1");
        weighstr = Double.toString(weight);
        actstr = activityString[activity][0];
        hourstr = Integer.toString(hour);
        minstr = Integer.toString(min);
        metstr = activityString[activity][1];
        foodstr = foodString[food][0];
        servstr = Double.toString(servings);

        add(lrgspace);
        add(uw);
        add(weigh);
        add(kg);
        add(medspace);
        add(sel1);
        add(sel2);
        add(sel3);
        add(sel4);
        add(sel5);
        add(sel6);
        add(sel7);
        add(sel8);
        add(sel9);
        add(sel10);
        add(sel11);
        add(sel12);
        add(sel13);

    }

    public void foodPaint(String[][] foodstring, String[][] actstring, double weight, int food, int servings, int activity, int hour, int min) {

        System.out.println("food1");
        weighstr = Double.toString(weight);
        foodstr = foodString[food][0];
        servstr = Integer.toString(servings);
        kjstr = foodString[food][1];
        actstr = activityString[activity][0];
        hourstr = Integer.toString(hour);
        minstr = Integer.toString(min);


        add(lrgspace);
        add(uw);
        add(weigh);
        add(kg);
        add(medspace);
        add(sel1);
        add(sel2);
        add(sel3);
        add(sel4);
        add(sel5);
        add(sel6);
        add(sel7);
        add(sel8);
        add(sel9);
        add(sel10);
        add(sel11);
        add(sel12);
        add(sel13);

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a single `JTextArea` rather than a slew of labels.  The result will end up better formatted and more reliable.

Comment: Did I missed to catch where the constructor is for `ResultPanel` Class, or you missed to specify that ? So question comes, where exactly is the Constructor you talking about in your `Question Heading` ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: As an aside, the line `ResultPanel a = new ResultPanel();` is wrong.  It creates a new panel that is never added to anything and never displayed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Why this empty string attached with `JLabel` Text as `JLabel sel3 = new JLabel("  -  kj  ");`, why this wicked space, and many more in your code ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw  I suspect that 'wicked space' leading/trailing the strings will be gobbled up before it appears. :)

Comment: The 'wicked space' is just me trying to make the output window look nice, I've had issues with other layouts, and am just looking to get it working at this stage, given more time I would be improving those types of things.

Comment: I hope you do remember this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793194/bordergrid-layouts/9793750#9793750), @AndrewThompson and to the @HughBurger OP, you can use Alignments, instead of spaces, like `JLabel.LEFT/RIGHT/CENTER`, and yyou can use it like `JLabel label = new JLabel("I am a JLAbel", JLabel.CENTER)` . And I hope that you hadn't forgotten to call your two methods, that are responsible for adding components to the `JPanel` i.e. `foodPaint(...) and activityPaint(...)`

Comment: Use a grid layout and get rid of all those nasty labels. Are you trying to add them to the panel at runtime?

Comment: @nIcEcOw  I had forgotten it - thanks for reminding me.  A fun thread. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your main method (or whatever method) that creates this JPanel also call the activityPaint(...) and foodPaint(...) methods?  If those methods are not called then they will never be added to the panel it seems.  If you want everything to be added when you create the JPanel then you must have your constructor call activityPaint() and foodPaint().

If the values of your JLables can't be set until something else occurs (like user input), then you can add the components when the JPanel is created and then later call the setText(...) method.  Just be sure if you do that to also set the size since changing the text will effect that.  I prefer to use *nameofjpanel*.setSize(*nameofjpanel*.getPreferredSize()).

Hope this helps you and I didn't completely miss what you're going for here.

Comment: I ended up moving the addTab arguments to the actionlisteners of the buttons i wanted to activate them, it's an overly complicated and under modulated way to do it but it works at least. Thanks for the help people.